# Delete pattern and line feed with tr or sed

Tags: sed, tr

The objective is to delete the line feed only when it is preceded by EOL, but when I use the tr command, it is deleting all line feeds and not just the ones preceded by EOL. Any suggestions?

```
tr -d 'EOL\012' <file1>file2
tr -d 'EOL\n' <file1>file2
```

This didn't work either. That's why I used the tr command. What have I got that is incorrect?

```
sed '/EOL\n/d' file1>file2
```

Comment: Use `sed` instead.

Comment: No it does not. I am trying to merge several lines onto the same line repeatedly throughout the file so that one logical record is also one physical record.

Comment: Does anyone have some syntax that could work?  I am still trying all sorts of ways with `sed` or `tr`  but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found some syntax that would allow for `EOL` and `\n` to be searched and deleted. Yay!

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/EOL\n/ /g' file1>file2
```

Comment: You're pulling all lines into the pattern space before doing any substitution - that's ugly... Use something like `sed ':t;/EOL$/{$!{N;//bt;};};s/EOL\n//g'` or `sed ':t;/EOL$/{$!N;s/EOL\n//;tt;}`